# Decreasing a variable by increments over time with setInterval

Tags: javascript, html

So right now, I am a beginner in coding and I'm having quite a few issues with the setInterval command. What I am trying to do is have a function that decreases a variable by 1 every time 5 seconds pass. However, although I have looked at many different threads with information about the setInterval command, none of them seem to fit my needs (although I may have missed something) and I have been unable to manipulate anything I have seen elsewhere to perform my function.

```
while (fullness <= 10) {
    setInterval(hungry{ fullness--; }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Let's see if you can provide some more information. What are you intending to do? What is `hungry`? Are you intending that to be a function call? Do you understand the difference between setTimeout and setInterval, to see which is more appropriate here?

Comment: Right now, I am trying to have a function that decreases the variable "fullness" by 1 every few seconds, and hungry is supposed to be the function that is "fullness--".

Answer (score 1):

Why your code is wrong:

```
//There is no need to loop and call setInterval multiple times
//setInterval will fire the callback function every x milliseconds,
//In your example you have it firing every 1 second(1000 milliseconds)
//while (fullness <= 10) {
    //setInterval(hungry{ fullness--; }, 1000);
//}
```

To fix this:
On page load (document.ready in jquery)
Do just one call to setInterval()

```
setInterval(function(){
   if(fullness <= 10){
      hungry{ fullness--; };  //Not sure about this line as it comes from your example
   }
}, 5000); //Pass second parameter to setInterval of 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds wait)
```

Comment: The "hungry{ fullness--; };" was supposed to imitate the "(function(){ alert("Hello");" part of the code, but I was kinf of confused by that.

Comment: @Cake_Commander If you just need to reduce fullness by one, you can remove the `hungry{}` and replace it with `fullness--` in my example.

Comment: Alright, I think I mostly get it now. Should I replace the "function()" with the desired function name like this?                         setInterval(HUNGER(){
   if(fullness <= 10){
      fullness--;
   }
}, 5000);

Comment: @Cake_Commander if you want to replace the function() with your own function name then you just use the name, like `setInterval(HUNGER, 5000);` And then in the `function HUNGER() { if(fullness <= 10) { fullness--; } }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set a variable for setInterval and then stop the iteration with clearInterval (important, otherwise the loop will iterate indefinitely). And check for fullness to be greater than 0.

```
var fullness = 10;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
   if(fullness > 0){
      fullness--;
   }
   else{
      clearInterval(timer);
   }
}, 5000);
```

Here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbme2cny/)

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to use `setInterval()` in a synchronous way rather than asynchronously.

When you call `setInterval(function, period)` it only begins a timer that calls the given `function` every `period` milliseconds. After calling `setInterval` javascript will continue to execute the next lines of code right away. If you were to check for your `fullness` value right after the while loop ends, you might notice it hasn't changed (yet!).

I suggest that you write a new function to handle changing `fullness` and reacting to the change:

```
function updateHunger() {
    fullness--;
    if (fullness < 10) {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
        //You have to call clearInterval() to stop the timer
        clearInterval(hungerTimer);
    }
 }
```

Then use `setInterval` like this:

```
//Using a variable to store the timer reference that we create
hungerTimer = setInterval(updateHunger, 5000);
```

Remember to declare the `hungerTimer` variable in a scope where it can be accessed from both `updateHunger()` and the method that calls `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are bumping into this is that JS runs in a single thread. Blocking it by waiting for 1 second would make the entire browser stall, which is why JS does not allow it and we do not have `sleep()` in JS, we have the Timers API.

But it's nonetheless nice to write straight up for-loops that look synchronous because that's how we "normally" think. That's why you can actually nowadays write something like this if using an engine with async and generator support:

```
// ES6 features

const sleeper = (x, timeout) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout, x));

function* timer(count, timeout) {
  for (let i = count; i >= 0; i--) {
    yield sleeper(i, timeout);
  }
}

async function main() {
  for (let i of timer(10, 1000)) {
    console.log(await i); // Blocks the main() function but not the JS main thread!
  }
}

main();  
console.log("The call to main() was non-blocking");
```